# Center according to element that has sibling with a larger width

Tags: html, css

I have a group of stats styled as shown below, but if I want to center the group, it will use the width of the descriptions that extend past and have a larger width. What's the easiest way to center according to the width of just the stat numbers and still have the descriptions below them?

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.stats {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}
.left-stats {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.left-stats .single-stat {
    text-align: right;
}
.right-stats {
    display: inline-block;
}
.right-stats .single-stat {
    text-align: left;
}
.single-stat {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.number {
    font: 60px"Bebas Neue";
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    
    <div class="stats">
        <div class="left-stats">
            <div class="single-stat">
                <div class="number">1,200</div>
                <div class="desc">Staff on campus supported</div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-stat">
                <div class="number">10</div>
                <div class="desc">Departments reached</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-stats">
            <div class="single-stat">
                <div class="number">06</div>
                <div class="desc">Different home states/countries</div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-stat">
                <div class="number">10</div>
                <div class="desc">People who love food and technology</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only 10 people love food and technology? This is why we will never meet aliens.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Center the group." What exactly are you wanting to center? And you want the width of the descriptions below the large numbers to match the width of the large numbers?

Comment: I would like the division between the left and right stats to be aligned with the center of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution using your HTML and using `display: table-cell` instead of `display: inline-block`.  Instead of a 40px margin to create the space between the columns, I added 20px left/right padding in the relevant elements.

Note that I added dotted blue borders for demonstration purposes, you can remove them.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.stats {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.left-stats {
  text-align: right;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.left-stats .single-stat {
  text-align: right;
}
.right-stats {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.right-stats .single-stat {
  text-align: left;
}
.single-stat {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.number {
  font: 60px"Bebas Neue";
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Header</h3>

  <div class="stats">
    <div class="left-stats">
      <div class="single-stat">
        <div class="number">1,200</div>
        <div class="desc">Staff on campus supported</div>
      </div>
      <div class="single-stat">
        <div class="number">10</div>
        <div class="desc">Departments reached</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-stats">
      <div class="single-stat">
        <div class="number">06</div>
        <div class="desc">Different home states/countries</div>
      </div>
      <div class="single-stat">
        <div class="number">10</div>
        <div class="desc">People who love food and technology</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
.number {
font: 60px"Bebas Neue";
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: -5px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, I'd like to keep the left and right stats aligned the way they are, and then have the division between the left and right stats be the center of the page, with the length of the descriptions arbitrary.